# Getting error 503 after deploying node backend on heroku. Anyone know why this could be?

Tags: node.js, heroku, deploying

After[image]

I am getting this error after deploying the app... Anyone know why this could be happening?

This is what I am getting in the console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

This is the heroku logs [image: heroku logs]

Comment: Can you provide you log info, do heroku logs --tail as displayed in the image

Comment: Hi Janith! Thanks for asking for that! I just added a screenshot of the heroku logs. I realized that is not reading my index file... Now I'm trying to figure out what I did wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion from Janith to check Heroku logs, I figured out the issue!

I previously set the routes on an app.js file when it needed to be pointing to my index.js file. Also, I needed to set nodemailer on a different file. After setting the routes in my index.js file and setting nodemailer on a separate file the issue was fixed.

Hope this helps anyone running to the same silly issue!

Thanks again @janith!

Comment: could you give more detail? because I got same issue on Heroku